# Could Google Chrome cache be causing hard drive corruptions?

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, fsck

I have gotten this error maybe 5 times now which, I originally thought I may have broke my ssd since I was messing with my laptop internals recently, but every time it mentions google chrome's cache in the log. This is also interesting considering chrome's cache folder is absolutely ginormous, for me currently containing over 26,000 files weighing at over 300mb.

I am running 18.04 ubuntu with kernel 4.19.8

Basically the error is when I boot it says there are errors and to run fsck manually on the drive and it just spits kinda random stuff at me so I have to click 'y' a bunch but it (always) mentions chrome.

Is there a fix for this that anybody knows of?

[image: Picture of screen on crash]

Comment: Do you have SSD-related messages in the system logs? How is the SSD connected to the machine? (If one of my systems started doing this, I'd suspect a slightly-loose cable that occasionally loses contact due to vibration.)

Comment: I have an M.2 ssd. I recently decided to add a sata ssd too so I was messing around internally in my laptop, and I did once take out the M.2 ssd just to look at it and stuck it back in. These errors also started happening days before I ever installed my sata ssd. I forgot to mention but the first time it happened, I was using chrome and I tried to download a file and it said failed so then I tried opening firefox and it wouldn't start so then I tried restarting chrome and it wouldn't start either so I restarted my pc and that was the first time I got the bug. I never had future software issues

Comment: @pt314 Any chance this could be a kernel issue? I used to use 4.14.21 a lot but because newer kernels had issues with sleep mode (wouldn't wake) but I recently started using 4.19.5 for reasons I cannot remember why. I believe I used 4.18 in the past too without issues but I cannot remember exactly to be frank. I swapped kernels around frequently trying to stay updated but not have bugs at the same time. I'll run 4.14.21 again for awhile and see if I get the error on this kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. I already twice had an extent problem with Chrome cache on SSD formatted to `btrfs`.

I used [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1363021/475611) to diagnose the issue.

```
find /mnt/mountpoint -xdev -inum xxxxxxxx
```

shown me a file from Chrome cache. After I deleted the file the problem has gone.

I think the same happens on `ext4`.

The SSD is new and reports no problems in SMART.

This must be a Chrome issue, because I have no other disk issues.